# Smart Contract test with nodejs fails with an error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, remix, ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to test a smart contract and want to do the following test.

```
it('Transfer tokens from owner should fail if owner has a low balance.', async () => {
                expect(await ptrTokenContract.transfer(receiverAddress1.address, 10000000)).to.be.revertedWith('Insufficient balance.Transfer failed !')
                console.log(await ptrTokenContract.balanceOf(receiverAddress1.address))                
            })
```

the value I am transferring is actrually greater than the owner's balance. But instead of passing the test fails with following error.

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Insufficient balance.Transfer failed !'
at Token.transfer (contracts/Token.sol:59)
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the position of the await, put it outside of the expect.

```
it('Transfer tokens from owner should fail if owner has a low balance.', async () => {
                await expect(ptrTokenContract.transfer(receiverAddress1.address, 10000000)).to.be.revertedWith('Insufficient balance.Transfer failed !')
                console.log(await ptrTokenContract.balanceOf(receiverAddress1.address))                
            })
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Can you explain why I have to put it outside ?

Comment: Because the way it works, putting the await outside will wait for the expect statement to resolve, which in our case it gets the revert from the transfer function and then actually compare it with the revertedWith.  To clear anymore doubts you can follow the official docs.

https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html

Please don't forget to accept my answer, it helps me to gain some reputation.